# Data to convert button's color

Tags: c#, loops

I have 8 simplebuttons.
I am using hercules to send data into my system. 
I'm sending address and led status.
When my led status is 01, I want button1 to turn green. 
When my led status is 02, I want button 2 to turn green and so on. 
I'm stuck and would like advise. The following is my code so far

```
        var address_Offset = Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(0, 2), 16);
        var led_stat = Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(2, 2), 16);
        var address = address_Offset - 0x3F;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            foreach (var btn in Button)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(btn.Tag) == address * 8 + i)
                {
                    if ((led_stat & 1) == 1)
                    {
                        btn.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        btn.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }

            led_stat >>= 2;
        }

        return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how can this loop `foreach (var btn in Button)`   Browse all buttons in your form or Container ? try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
       {   
          foreach (Control c in Form1.Controls)
                {
                   if (c is Button)
                     {
                       Button btn  = (c as CheckBox);
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(btn.Tag) == address * 8 + i)
                         {
                          if ((led_stat & 1) == 1)
                            {
                                btn.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                btn.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
        led_stat >>= 2;
            }

            return;
```

Comment: Button is a list of simplebutton. So, Button contains 8 simplebuttons.